# Newtonsoft - How to parse an array of objects

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I just want to get this JSON into some kind of object. `JArray` and `JToken` are completely confusing to me.

I can create a class so that Newtonsoft knows what to map to but if you will notice the objects have the structure of: `{ "anAnimal": { foo: 1, bar: 2 }}` and I don't know what that mapper object will look like. I'm pretty sure this should just work instantly with zero thought on my part.

```cs
var myFavoriteAnimalsJson = @"
[
    {
        ""Dog"": {
            ""cuteness"": ""7.123"",
            ""usefulness"": ""5.2"",
        }
    },
    {
        ""Cat"": {
            ""cuteness"": ""8.3"",
            ""usefulness"": ""0"",
        }
    }
]";

var jArray = new JArray(myFavoriteAnimalsJson);
// grab the dog object. or the cat object. HOW CUTE IS THE DOG?
```

Comment: Is the Dog object always going to be the first in the array, or do you need to determine which one it is?

Comment: Do you control the schema of this JSON? If so, you might want to simplify it. Your array has a list of objects, which has a property of Dog _or_ Cat, which those properties _themselves_ are objects. Might be easier to move everything "up one level".

Comment: no, sometimes it will be dog. sometimes it will be killer whale. nope, i don't control it. I could grab this with node.js easily and parse it into something a little easier for c# but that's too much. once this works it will be way better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can deserialize it to a `List<Dictionary<string, AnimalData>>`

```cs
class AnimalData
{
    public decimal cuteness;
    public decimal usefulness;
}
```

```cs
var myFavoriteAnimalsJson = @"
[
    {
        ""Dog"": {
            ""cuteness"": ""7.123"",
            ""usefulness"": ""5.2"",
        }
    },
    {
        ""Cat"": {
            ""cuteness"": ""8.3"",
            ""usefulness"": ""0"",
        }
    }
]";

var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, AnimalData>>>(myFavoriteAnimalsJson);
```

Now each list item contains a dictionary with a single key of `Dog` `Cat`...

Comment: Nice! This is actually what I was trying to do. I had the Dictionary<string, animal> but not the List.

Answer (score 4):

With [`.SelectToken()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SelectToken.htm) to construct the JSON path query logic.

The below sample to query the first item of `animals` to get the object of "Dog" token and its value.

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

JArray animals = JArray.Parse(myFavoriteAnimalsJson);
        
var dog = animals[0].SelectToken("Dog");

Console.WriteLine(dog);
Console.WriteLine(dog["cuteness"]);
```

[Sample Program](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6W6Ph8)

Output

> {
> "cuteness": "7.123",
> "usefulness": "5.2"
> }
>
> 7.123

Comment: Just a note, this assumes that Dog is always the first element. You can pass a more complex JSONPath to SelectToken when it's not in the first element. `animals.SelectToken("$[*].Dog");`

Comment: Hi @gunr2171, good hints and explanation for the scenario! Thanks for the guidance. =)

Comment: Oh and as for the getting the identifier of each object (Cat, Dog) I found this code which works. https://www.javaer101.com/en/article/8638748.html `var jArray = JArray.Parse(myFavoriteAnimalsJson);
var animals = jArray.Children<JObject>();
foreach(var animal in animals)
{
    foreach(JProperty prop in animal.Properties())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(prop.Name);
    }
}`
How is the the standard C# JSON library. Pure crap UI IMO.

Answer (score 0):

If you start from a serialized JSON, i.e. a string, you have to parse it:

```
var jArray = JArray.Parse(myFavoriteAnimalsJson);
```

Comment: okay that works but then it gives me a JToken. i hate to ask but ...how does one read information out of a JToken? For example, how would I know if I have the Dog or Cat JToken?

Comment: There is some docs about this library here: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryingLINQtoJSON.htm
The idea behind it is to shape the JSON structure into a node tree, so that it can be transversed and manipulated easily. In the past, I used a lot this way to manage JSON, although it's rather expensive in terms of memory occupation.